# SQL Oracle - Clob to Number

Tags: sql, query, oracle, float

Tenho uma tabela a qual não da para ser remodelada, ela é composta por um campo CLOB o qual tem valores decimais separados por ponto ex:(123.12)

Preciso que este campo seja retornado pra mim no resultado como um number, decimal, ,float ou qualquer tipo que seja numérico real.

Como faço isso no select ?

Ja tentei fazer:

Select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CLOB)) FROM TABELA, por exemplo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860526/how-to-convert-clob-to-varchar2-inside-oracle-pl-sql  converte para char e depois para number , atenção ao formato de número usado https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm   usar o tipo correto evita que coisas banais virem complicações ...

Answer (score 2):

O problema é os valores com **ponto e não virgula**, para converter para valor numérico você precisa fazer um REPLACE, Substituindo . (ponto) por , (virgula)

Segue exemplo:

```
--CRIANDO TABELA TESTE
CREATE TABLE teste_clob(
campo_clob CLOB
);

--INSERINDO DADO TESTE
INSERT INTO teste_clob
(campo_clob)
VALUES
('123.12');

--VERIFICANDO VALOR CLOB
SELECT campo_clob FROM teste_clob;

--CONVERTENDO FORMATO EXPLICATIVO
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(valor_char,'.',',')) AS valor_number
FROM(
SELECT CAST(campo_clob AS VARCHAR2(200)) AS valor_char 
FROM teste_clob)

--CONVERTENDO FORMATO SIMPLIFICADO
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(campo_clob,'.',',')) AS RESULTADO 
FROM teste_clob;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b86141/5. Nice, nem era preciso replace

Comment: Miguel, isso depende da configuração do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, agradeço a todos que responderam, mas depois de tanto bater a cabeça consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte forma.
Não é algo bonito, mas esta funcionando como eu esperava.

TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAST(AMOUNT AS VARCHAR2(200))),'9999999999999999999.999999999') AS AMOUNT,

Comment: Devias aceitar a resposta que está correta, esta maneira sinceramente nem faz muito sentido. Aqui está: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b86141/5

Comment: Ok, no link que voce passou funcionou ok.
Mas o problema é, assim que faço o mesmo na base de dados oracle, acontece isso:
ORA-01722: número inválido
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: nesse caso o replace é então necessário, como está na outra resposta creio que funciona